# overriding FOSUserBundle Registration Form Type

Tags: php, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I created a Bundle called AccountBundle in the path `/src/EF/Bundle/`. This overrides the FOSUserBundle for customization.

```
namespace EF\Bundle\AccountBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class EFAccountBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Then, in the path AccountBundle/Form/Type, I am trying to override RegistrationType

```
namespace EF\Bundle\AccountBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

class UserRegistrationFormType extends BaseRegistrationFormType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    /**
     * @param object $builder FormBuilderInterface
     * @param array $options Options that override FOSUserBundle
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // Adding custom Fields to override FOS User bundle
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', null, array('label' => 'fos.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ef_account_registration';
    }
}
```

Added a service on services.xml on AccountBundle/Resources/config as

```
<!-- src/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/registration.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<services>

       <service id="fos_user.registration.form.type" class="EF\Bundle\AccountBundle\Form\Type\UserRegistrationFormType">
            <tag name="form.type" alias="ef_account_registration" />
            <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
        </service>
  </services>

</container>
```

Then made a change in the config file, /app/config/config.yml as

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MH\Security\User
    #user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Propel\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
        form:
            type: ef_account_registration
```

But i get an error while trying to do register,

> Could not load type "ef_account_registration" 500 Internal Server
>   Error - FormException

But if I change the `ef_account_registration` with `fos_user_registration`, then it works. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with override and what steps had you followed?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete this part:

```
form:
            type: ef_account_registration
```

and I think in UserRegistrationFormType you only need the buildForm method, all the others can be deleted and in your sevice (I use yml):

```
fos_user.registration.form.type:
        class: YOUR_CLASS
        tags:
             - { name: 'form.type', alias: 'fos_user_registration' }
        arguments:
             - %fos_user.model.user.class%
```

and it works for me